# Nested Sets: Retrieving Multiple Paths

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, nested-sets

Is it possible to retrieve multiple paths from MySQL nested sets? Emphasis is on the second line of the where condition.

```
SELECT parent.name
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.name = 'Name1' OR node.name = 'Name2'
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Comment: Just add a parentheses to the node names `(node.name = 'Name1' OR node.name = 'Name2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.

In `SQL`, `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so you need to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT  parent.name
FROM    nested_category AS node
JOIN    nested_category AS parent
ON      node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
WHERE   node.name IN ('Name1', 'Name2')
ORDER BY
        node.lft;
```

This query is quite inefficient in `MySQL` because the join condition is not sargable.

You may want to store your sets as `LineString` and use spatial indexes to speed up the query.

See this entry in my blogs for details:

- [**Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)